# Why do need to 'reload the policy' in java control panel to enable the proper java.policy?

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, jnlp

I have an applet that uses a policy file and for some reason the policy is loaded on some machines but not on others. The following is a snippet of my JNLP file:

```
<resources>
   <property name="java.security.policy" value="http://192.168.5.134:50000/pacs-c/java.policy"/>
   <property name="java.security.auth.login.config" value="http://192.168.5.134:50000/pacs-c/Softmedical_jaas.config"/>
</resources>
```

On machines where the applet does not work properly if I open the java console and type 'r' or reload the policy, the applet starts working just fine. But just can't figure out why it does this.

Is there a way to force loading a policy? I just can't understand why I have issues on some machines.

### EDIT

> The jars are signed properly.

Also

> The certificate is installed on each machine and it matches the signing key.